# AJAX. PHP. CURL. Ajax request to site, with another encoding

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I try to parse one page from my another site. For it i use cUrl

Request (send data to script):

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'wordstat/ajax?query='+query+'&page='+page+'&id='+id,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

This script (wordstat/ajax), do request to my second site via controller:

Controller:

```
public function ajax()
{
    $this->model->auth();
    echo $this->model->parse_uri($_GET['page'],$_GET['query']);

}
```

Model:

```
public function parse_uri($url,$word)
{
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://wordstat/rating.php?url=".$url."&word=".$word."&gap=3");

    $html = mb_convert_encoding(str_replace("\n","",curl_exec($this->curl)), "utf-8", "windows-1251");
    preg_match('/<span style="font-size:14px" class=red>(.*)<\/span>/U',$html,$matches);
    return $matches;
}
```

If i put in browser  `http://localhost/wordstat/ajax?page=page&url=url` and open this page, then 
she return value of `<span style="font-size:14px" class=red>` of another site correctly

But when i do it via Ajax request, it's always return empty Array

What i doin wrong?
Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem resolved**

```
    $url = str_replace(" ","",$url);
    $word = str_replace(" ","",$word);

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://parser/rating.php?url=".$url."&word=".$word."&gap=3");

    $html = str_replace("\n","",curl_exec($this->curl));
    preg_match('/<span style="font-size:14px" class=red>(.*)<\/span>/U',$html,$matches);

    return $matches;
```

Thanks to anyoune, who tried help

Comment: So what was the problem ? Write more info in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You use directly in browser

```
wordstat/ajax?page=page&url=url
```

but ajax use

```
wordstat/ajax?query='+query+'&page='+page+'&id='+id
```

Perhaps different arguments give you different results.

Comment: I tried use in ajax `'wordstat/ajax?query='+query+'&page='+page` but it still not work

Comment: You use in browser address without `query`. Ajax use address with `query`. You use `query` as `word` in rating.php